# How do I add an unlimited amount of employees to a program?

Tags: java, database, eclipse, list

the idea is to add an employee inside the program then another employee and so on.

Through researching how to do this I have come across

```
    public class Employee { 
        private String name; 
        private int Id; 

        public Employee(String empName, int empId) { 
            name = empName; 
            Id = empId; 
        } 
    }

    ...

    Employee Jack = new Employee("Jack",001);
```

All of the code I am coming across in tutorials and examples is storing variables inside the actual programming code and not stored when the program is running.

This is not what I am trying to do however. I want to input the name by user input and store it in the program so that the name entered is saved then I want to be able to add another and another so eventually I end up with a list of employees by user input.

Any advice would be great

Thanks

Comment: `unlimited` sounds a little too much don't you think ;-)

Comment: You said it yourself. Use a list.

Comment: I really feel a lack of proper research or at least doing a proper tutorial, for example : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/intro/

Comment: Use a new java.util.Scanner(System.in) to take the User input and scan for next() employee name and next() employee ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Java Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html).  You can use a List like Luiggi suggested, or you may want to use a Map so that you can look them up by name or Id.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Employee
{
  private final String name;
  private final int Id;
  private static Map<String, Employee> employeesByName = new HashMap<String, Employee>();
  private static Map<Integer, Employee> employeesById = new HashMap<Integer, Employee>();

  public Employee(String empName, int empId)
  {
    name = empName;
    Id = empId;
    employeesByName.put(name, this);
    employeesById.put(Id, this);
  }

  public static Employee getEmployeeByName(String name)
  {
    return employeesByName.get(name);
  }

  public static Employee getEmployeeById(int Id)
  {
    return employeesById.get(Id);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1 :**

If you just want to persist the list of employees for a single run of the program you can store the employees in some datastructure (ArrayList, Map, Set). The choice of data structure depends on the operations that you want to perform on this collection of Employees.

Example : using a List

```
 List<Employee> employeeCollection = new ArrayList<Employee>(): 
 employeeCollection.add(new Employee("Kakarot" , 1));
 employeeCollection.add(new Employee("John Doe" , 2));
```

**Option 2 :** 
If you want to persist the data in such a way that its available all the time (even when you shut down the Program and then launch it again) , you have the following options :

1) Store data in a Text file in some human readable format. eg  :

```
 Kakarot|33
 John Doe|2
```

So now ehen your program starts read this file and construct the list of all previously inserted employees.

2) Store data in some Dataase eg: Oracle, MySql etc

3) Serialize the List of employees to a file on the disk. And read the file at the start of the program.

Comment: Theres also option 3 (in my opinion easier than the text file as you don't have to parse it); serialise the list

Comment: yes I was thinking of addig that, but it gets complicated depending on the object Hierarchy and other constraints. But definitely something to consider

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html), which allows growing in size dynamically.

```
List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
Employee employee;
employee = new Employee("Luiggi", 1);
employeeList.add(e);
employee = new Employee("user3620639", 2);
employeeList.add(e);
System.out.println(employeeList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers to this question take care of the list aspect. As for the user input, you have a few options.

If you want to use a GUI approach, you can use `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` to obtain user input:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int i = 0;
    List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<Employee>();

    do {
        String username = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insert new employee name");
        i++;

        empList.add(new Employee(username, i));
    } while (/*some condition for continued execution*/);

    System.out.println(empList);
}
```

If you're using just a text based command line interface, you'd use a `BufferedReader`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 0;
    List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    do {
        String username = reader.readLine();
        i++;

        empList.add(new Employee(username, i));
    } while (/*some codition for continued execution*/);

    System.out.println(empList);
}
```